# Unable to delete Amazon EBS snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot

I am unable to delete an Amazon EBS snapshot because the console says that:

> The snapshot snap-xyz is currently in use by ami-1234

I made the snapshot with the intention of moving the server between accounts, which I have done, but now do not wish to keep the snapshot (incurring charges in this account).

The documentation I can find indicates that to remove the snapshot the server must be no longer required.

Is there a way to separate the two, keep the server and delete the snapshot?

Comment: According to the error, it's in use by an AMI. Delete the AMI, then delete the snapshot.

Answer (score 3):

If you are done with moving the server across accounts, then it means that you no longer need the AMI also. You need to deregister the AMI and then you can delete the snapshot. Details are mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/snapshot-in-use-error/).

> Before you attempt to delete an EBS snapshot, make sure that the AMI
>   isn’t currently in use. AMIs can be used with a variety of AWS
>   services, such as Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2), AWS Auto
>   Scaling, AWS CloudFormation, and more. If you delete an AMI that’s
>   used by another service or application, the function of that service
>   or application might be affected.
>
> If you no longer need the EBS snapshot or its associated AMI,
>   deregister the AMI. Then, delete the EBS snapshot in the Amazon EC2
>   console.